# Keyboard shortcut to open Extensions menu in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I open the Keyboard Shortcut menu far more often than I'd like to admit. How do I open this with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Here's a list of Chrome shortcuts: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450. There doesn't seem to be one dedicated to opening extensions, so you might have to get an extension to customize this.
(You COULD do `⌘-,` to open the settings, and then navigate to extensions, but it's probably not what you're looking for.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an official keyboard shortcut built into Chrome for the Extensions menu. However, without using additional software, there are still ways to be able to access the menu relatively quickly.

You can add the Extensions menu as a bookmark on the bookmarks bar. Its URL is chrome://extensions/.

[image: Extensions menu as a bookmark]

This puts it one click away. However, if you want to be able to access it from the keyboard only, there is another way. Right-click the Omnibar and choose "Edit search engines". Under "Other search engines", fill in the information as shown, and then choose Done.

[image: Edit search engines]

This creates a "search engine" which can be accessed through the keyword 'ex'. Now, to access Extensions, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the Omnibar, type `ex`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Of course, you can customize the "ex" keyword.

Comment: This is a bit of a workaround but it's a very good solution. I added bindings for my search engines (Stack Overflow, UX.stackexchange, etc) too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Extensions is a menu item in Chrome, you can assign it a keyboard shortcut through OS X's System Preferences.

- Go to the 'Keyboard' Panel
- Select the 'Shortcuts' tab
- Choose 'App Shortcuts' from the left column
- Click the <kbd>+</kbd> under the right column to add Google Chrome as an App in the list.
- In the pop-up, type "Extensions" (without quotes) in the space beside 'Menu Title'
- Assign a keyboard shortcut (I use <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> for all my personal shortcuts so I used <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for this one)

Done.

:)

Yahenda